# Script task generates Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have multiple SSIS packages which then included into a single master package. When I'm running this job. I checked individual packages by running it manually and all went green - means executed successfully. However, from job,Getting below error:

> Executed as user: AA\xx_dev. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility     Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All   rights reserved.    Started:  7:40:34 PM  Error: 2016-01-13 19:40:37.04       Code: 0x00000001     Source: Source File Appearance_Validation_Transfer        Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been   thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException:   Index was outside the bounds of the array.     at ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1.csproj.ScriptMain.Get_Entity_Name(String FileName)     at ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1.csproj.ScriptMain.Validate_File_Name(String FileName, String FileExt)     at ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1.csproj.ScriptMain.Validate_Files(String FileName)     at ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)     at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)     at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  7:40:34 PM  Finished: 7:40:37 PM  Elapsed:  3.01 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

How can I know, which step got failed? There are around 10 packages included into master package. What does this error means? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you enabled any breakpoints in you script component either master package  or child packages. If yes remove breakpoints and then run the job.

Comment: 1) Find the Script Task amongst those packages named "Source File Appearance_Validation_Transfer Description" It's doing *something* such that it's generating `IndexOutOfBoundsException` Since we do not have access to your Code, any parameters or configurations for the packages and your environment, it's impossible to even hazard a guess as to why it's throwing an exception.

Comment: 2) Patch your server. [10.50.4000](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2008r2) is SP2 which was released in 2012. SP3 was released in 2014. It is now 2016. You are severely out of a patching cycle.

Comment: 3) You have a method in the script task (back to #1) called `Get_Entity_Name` which takes a FileName as a parameter. Using my prophetic skills, I suspect someone is using string manipulation to determine file name, extension, parent path, etc and doing it wrong for the supplied run-time value. A UNC is a great example of where people get this wrong. Relative paths also a fine case. If you discover this assumption is true, use the library methods available in `System.IO.Path`

Answer (score 0):

After searching this (ST_a3ed049745fb4a87b5abac55eb724bf1) in whole solution; I got to know, which particular script task was showing error. And after my debug error got fixed.